# Image thresholding fails to completely remove dotted noise from the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-thresholding

I am working on some images where I have to do some preprocessing operations to remove anything and keep only the writing.
For that, I used different thresholding methods (adaptive mean threshold, adaptive gaussian threshold, ...). The best results I got are with adaptive mean threshold. However using the adaptive mean threshold didn't only remove the unwanted 'noise', but it also removed a part of the writing!
This is the code I used:

```
src = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
height, width = src.shape
blockSize = 35
C = 23
amtImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(src, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, blockSize, C)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', amtImage)
```

**INPUT IMAGES:** *for confidentiality reasons, these images are taken from the Internet!*

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
**OUTPUT IMAGES:**

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I tried to remove the dotted noise by using the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('output.jpg', 0)
_, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] #get CC_STAT_AREA component
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 10:   #filter small dotted regions
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)
cv2.imwrite('another_output.jpg, res)
```

This is an Example of what I got:

[image]

Although the Adaptive mean threshold did well, but the final result still not good enough to be OCR-ed (using Tesseract).
Can anyone please suggest some modifications or any ideas in order to improve the quality of the threshold and keep only the writing in the final image?
Sorry for being too long, and thank you!

Comment: Don’t threshold right away, then try to fix up the binary image. Filter the grey-scale image to suppress stuff you don’t need, then threshold at the very end.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. after I tried it, much more noise was suppressed, but a part of the writing was merged with the photo in (in the middle of the image) the background.